# Datastax Java Driver failed to scan an entire table

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

I iterated over the entire table and received less partitions than expected.
Initially, I thought that it must be something wrong on my end, but after checking the existence of every row (I have a list of billions of keys with which I used) by using simple where query, and also verifying the expected number with the spark connector, I conclude that it can't be anything other than the driver.

I have billions of data rows, yet receiving half a billion less.

anyone else encountered this issue and was able to resolve it?

**adding code snippet**

The structure of the table is a simple counter table ,

```
CREATE TABLE counter_data (
  id text,
  name text,
  count_val counter,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
) ;
```

public class CountTable {

```
private Session session;
private Statement countQuery;
public void initSession(String table) {
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    queryOptions.setFetchSize(100);
    QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder().build();
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("ip").withPort(9042)
            .build();
    cluster.register(queryLogger);
    this.session = cluster.connect("ks");
    this.countQuery = QueryBuilder.select("id").from(table);
}


public void performCount(){
    ResultSet results = session.execute(countQuery);
    int count = 0;
    String lastKey = "";
    results.iterator();
    for (Row row : results) {
        String key = row.getString(0);
        if (!key.equals(lastKey)) {
            lastKey = key;
            count++;
        }
    }
    session.close();
    System.out.println("count is "+count);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CountTable countTable = new CountTable();
    countTable.initSession("counter_data");
    countTable.performCount();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post more details - table structure, code, etc.

Comment: @AlexOtt , thanks Alex, added the code

Comment: @roeezi so you have a counter table but doesn't get the output from counter_value? How many nodes are in this cassandra cluster and what is the replication factor for the keyspace?

Comment: @dilsingi , cluster of 10 nodes, replication factor of 3, on top of ec2 , I'm using version 3.11 and the driver is 3.3.2 

it's not about the counter_value though, my problem is that that when I scan  a table with billions of partition keys, the final count is 10-15% less than expected, even though every expected key existence was checked directly  . 

I ran a spark count job as well, and with it, I received the right number. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking your code, the consistency level requested is ONE, compared to a dirty read in RDBMS world.

> queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

For stronger consistency, that is to get back all records use local_quorum. Update your code as follows

> queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);

local_quorum guarantees that majority of the nodes in the replica (in your case 2 out of 3) respond to the read request and hence stronger consistency resulting in accurate number of rows. Here is documentation reference on [consistency.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html)

Comment: I'll give it a try, though I did attempt to run with ALL consistency and still got much less than expected.

Comment: Hi @dilsingi  , I tried to replace the consistency level to quorum and still received much less than expected. 

Also , if I use distinct query, the count is higher, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the scale of the table.  

in the meanwhile, I'm using spark for this kind of aggregations, though it still concerns me that there are some inaccuracies in the driver